# Unique Algorithm for Product Filtering

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, codeigniter

I've been working on a custom product filter in CodeIgniter. The framework I'm using isn't necessarily important to the algorithm I need to create. I've planned it out in different ways and haven't figured the algorithm out yet.

Basically I'll have a variable number of arrays within an array (e.g.: array(array(123, 124), array(125, 126, 127), array(128, 129, 127, 130, [...])). They will all be in that format as numbers being their values.

My solution will iterate through the main array and check each inner array against its previous array to get only duplicate values. (e.g.: get first array >> get second array and merge with first >> get duplicates from results >> get third array and merge with duplicates, etc...)

I've easily created the function to retrieve duplicate values from a single array, but my solution seems to be much more complex... thanks!

Comment: `array_intersect()` sounds like it does what you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Why would you be merging values from the third array with duplicates from array 1 and 2?

Comment: array_intersect() is worth giving a try in the overall algorithm. The ultimate goal is to go in order for each array, limiting to duplicate values. That's why I thought about merging values from the 3rd array with the results of duplicates of the previous arrays. So essentially I have one resulting array and the next (3rd) array to intersect against it.

Comment: Looks like the array_intersect function will do the trick. I might have been complicating things by creating a get_duplicates function. I used it when I needed to get only duplicate values from a single array.